# CSS - I can't view any element below a div I made

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm making a portfolio page and I set the initial page on opening to a height of '100vh' and width '100%',which works well. However, I can't scroll down to any other element I make below it. It takes up the whole page and makes other elements disappear.

```
return(
      <div>
        <Navbar/>
        
         <section className="valign-wrapper" style={{height: '100vh',width:'100%'}}>
          <div className="center-align" style={{width:'100vw'}}>

       
            <h1 className="animate__animated animate__fadeInDown">Hi, I'm Chijindu</h1>
            
            <div>
            <h3 style={{display:'inline-block',marginRight:'8px',marginTop:'-20px'}} className="animate__animated animate__fadeInLeft">a frontend </h3> <h3 style={{display:'inline-block',marginTop:'-20px'}} className=" green-text animate__animated animate__fadeInRight">developer...</h3>

            </div>
        </div>

        
        

      </section>

        <div class="row red">
      <div class="col s1">1</div>
      <div class="col s1">2</div>
      <div class="col s1">3</div>
      <div class="col s1">4</div>
      <div class="col s1">5</div>
      <div class="col s1">6</div>
      <div class="col s1">7</div>
      <div class="col s1">8</div>
      <div class="col s1">9</div>
      <div class="col s1">10</div>
      <div class="col s1">11</div>
      <div class="col s1">12</div>
    </div>
       
        
        </div>
        

        
        )
```

The viewport height and width are set in the *section* tag. None of the *rows or column* elements below show, even when zoomed out. I can't even scroll down.
Although on browser inspection, it indicates that the rows and columns DO exist, Thanks.

Apologies for all the inline styling.

EDITED: I also added a background with styles I copied and am not sure of=>

```
.valign-wrapper {
  background: url('./img/img001.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  
}
```

Could that be affecting other elements?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: try changing the parent (outer most) <div> to <div style={{ overflowY : 'scroll' }} >

Comment: Tried it,still not scrolling

Comment: please create a minimum working demo on codesandbox.io

Comment: I fixed it,it was my bad. I copied a css code for a loading screen that had body,html{overflow:hidden}.Clearing it fixed it. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

First try to mention the viewport height for the entire window like:

```
*,
html,
body{
  height:95vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it,it was my bad. I copied a css code for a loading screen that had `body,html{overflow:hidden}`
. Thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using height: 100vh, please use min-height: 100vh.